# Give variable name but not its value to a function

Tags: javascript

To remove tedious code i would like to create a function to simplify it.
So to change the settings that i stored in an object, I created this.

```
var settings = {
    color : 'red'
    //one of many settings
};
alert(settings.color); // returns red
function changeValue(property, value){
    settings.property = value;
}
changeValue('color', 'blue');
alert(settings.color); // still return red
```

it seems like its treated as a string instead.
And if i try this:

```
function changeValue(object, value){
    object = value;
}
changeValue(settings.color, 'blue');
```

it would only give the function the value which is 'red'.
and this:

```
changeValue('settings.color', 'blue');
```

would not work obviously.

So how do i solve this ? How do i pass down a variable to a function but not its value so it can be altered ?

Note: the function is simplified for now, but would contain a lot more magic when it works.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the *object* and the *name of the property that you want to change* as separate arguments:

```
function changeValue(obj, prop, value) {
    obj[prop] = value;
}

changeValue(settings, "color", "blue");
```

Assuming `var prop = "color"` then `obj[prop]` is equivalent to `obj.color`. The first notation allows you to dynamically specify the property that should be changed.

Comment: Cheers. New to javascript so i had no idea of this method.

Answer (score 1):

when you do settings.color you get a value, rather than object. You'd have to do something like

```
function changeValue(object, field, value){
    object[field] = value;
}
```

used like

```
changeValue(settings, 'color', 'blue')
```

which may not actually reduce time for you at all..

---

EDIT::
I have made this function for you. But please.. Don't ever use it.

```
var settings = {
    color : "blue"
}

function setField(str, value){
    var args = str.split(".").reverse();
    var obj = window[args.pop()];
    while(args.length -  1 > 0) 
        obj = obj[args.pop()]
    obj[args.pop()] = value;
}

alert(settings.color);
setField("settings.color", "red");
alert(settings.color);
```

Comment: since i wanted to "remove tedious code", this would definitely go against it.

Comment: @EinarLöve 'tedious code'? My 'solution' does exactly what you want. setField("settings.color", "red") works as you wanted. I also gave the 'correct' way of doing it. Although your original requirement is wrong, and both solutions should not be used (including lwburk's code (which is identical to mine))

Comment: You first function is definitely just what im looking for. my previous comment was a respond to your edit.